# Making the web server as a relay between two sides

Tags: php, android, web-applications, web

I want to control a robot from the web, the robot is connected to Android device. The operation will be as the following :

- a web application written using JavaScript and HTML runs on desktop computer  which takes the keyboard input from the user and send them to the android device connected to the robot.
- the android device receive the commands and then send them to Arduino board which used to control the robot.

But how should I deliver the data to the Android device which doesn't has a static IP address?

I have two approaches to solve that :

1. the JavaScript application sends the keyboard input to a web server runs PHP and MySQL , then the php application store the data on the MySQL database. An application runs on Android connected to that web server and extract the data from the MySQL database.
2. the JavaScript sends the data to the web server. The android application connected to the web server receives the data directly so the web server is just used as a relay.

The first approach is easy to do but its slow , so my question is...

How to implement the second approach and which web technologies should I use to implement it? And how to make the web server works as relay between two sides?

PS : I am planning to use 000webhost.com as web server. so I will not use my own server

Comment: This sounds like a job for Google Cloud Messaging: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Quasdunk...you can put it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I think you can accept xbonez' answer as well, since he also mentions some alternatives :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have your Android application poll the webserver for outstanding commands. This is a little inefficient in terms of data usage, but if you're on an unlimited 3G plan / wi-fi, you could live with it. It will be very easy to implement.

Alternatively, set up a TCP server on your server, and have your Android application open a socket connection with the server. This way, your web application can send commands to the server which will immediately stream them to the Android device. It will be slightly harder to implement, but will be more efficient and robust if done right.

PS - Most shared servers don't allow you to open a TCP server on your host so you might be forced to go with the first option.

PPS - I wasn't aware of Google Cloud Messaging. It seems to be a good solution for you what you're attempting to achieve. You should have a look into it.